# Exclude outliers from average calculation

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, microsoft-excel-2007, worksheet-function

I want to calculate the average of numbers given in Column A as shown in the figure below. But I want to base the average on values *equal to or greater than 15 and equal to or less than 25*, via the limits specified in cells `E11` and `E12`. For example, 100 and all those in Column B marked FALSE should be excluded.

How could I achieve this in Excel?

[image: SU 05024 example]

Comment: @pnuts sorry means between 15 and 25.

Comment: Probably what you really want is a median...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `AVERAGEIFS(average_range,criteria_range1,criteria1,criteria_range2,criteria2…)`
 which returns the average (arithmetic mean) of all cells that meet multiple criteria.

Enter this formula in any available cell...

> `=AVERAGEIFS(A1:A18,A1:A18,"<25",A1:A18,">15")`

If your conditional values are in `E11` and `E12` you can enter this formula...

> `=AVERAGEIFS(A1:A18,A1:A18,"<"&E12,A1:A18,">"&E11)`

which are both equal to 22 in your case.

-I hope this helps

Comment: When i pasted the formula it return the zero..

Comment: This works for me. Remember to update calculations (F9) and ensure the cell references are correct to the sheet you are working with.

Answer (score 2):

You can use AVERAGEIF in your version of Excel for single conditions.

But, since you have multiple conditions, I suggest you use SUMPRODUCT:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(($A$1:$A$19>$E$11)*($A$1:$A$19<$E$12)*($A$1:$A$19))/SUMPRODUCT(($A$1:$A$19>$E$11)*($A$1:$A$19<$E$12))
```

The numerator will return the sum of those numbers in that range that fall in your target range.

The denominator will return the count of those numbers in that range that fall in your target range.

Comment: It return me the zero answer ..why is it so?

Comment: This also works for me. Remember to update calculations (F9) and ensure the cell references are correct to the sheet you are working with.

Answer (score 2):

A long winded version that might help with understanding where other answers are not 'performing' as they should or that could be educational, also considers entire columns that may make subsequent expansion trouble-free:

> =SUMIFS(A:A,A:A,">="&$E$12,A:A,"<="&$E$11)/COUNTIFS(A:A,">="&$E$12,A:A,"<="&$E$11)

Note that Formulas > Formula Auditing - Evaluate Formula, Evaluate will step through the calculation process and so may help to pin down an errors.

Note answer provided is 21.66667 (with or without value in `A19`) and that I switched 25 to `E11` and 15 to `E12`.